# Necesito actualizar (UPDATE) el resultado de un select en mysql para node js y myadminphp no me acepta la instrucción

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs

Estoy trabajando un `socket.io` para actualizar unas base de datos. Los datos leídos y servidos por `socket.io` a un archivo `pug` los quiero marcar con `estado=1`.

Inicialmente el valor es de 0.

Quiero que el `SELECT` lea 10 artículos y queden en consulta para realizar la actualización de esos registros, pero he realizado diversidad de opciones y ni `myadminphp` ni `node js` admiten el `update` del `select`.

```
UPDATE consulta 
SET consulta.estado=1 
FROM 
  (SELECT * AS consulta 
  FROM articulos 
  WHERE articulos.estado<>1 LIMIT 1, 10 
  AS consulta);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estoy seguro si esa consulta debería funcionar, lo más probable es que no. Deberías ver si el id de los registros donde corre el update se encuentra en los registros que devuelve la sub consulta.

Me imagino una consulta así:

```
UPDATE consulta
  SET estado = 1
  WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id FROM (
      SELECT id FROM consulta
        WHERE estado <> 1
        LIMIT 1, 10
    ) tmp
  )
```

Comment: Gracias. Me indico el camino con los indices. Funcionó con limit 0,10 para diez registros afectados. Una duda: tmp es un alias que no empleo cierto?. En ese caso, lo puedo quitar?. La solución para mi:  UPDATE articulos
  SET estado = 1
  WHERE codigo IN (
    SELECT codigo FROM (
      SELECT codigo FROM articulos
        WHERE estado <> 1
        LIMIT 0, 10
    ) tmp
  )

Comment: En efecto, es un alias. No deberías tener problemas al quitarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser que el usuario que esta gestionando la base de datos no puede hacer update, así que debes de darle permisos con GRANT en la base de datos para que pueda actualizar, verifica los permisos del usuario que estas usando y ahí veras hasta donde puedes hacer.

Comment: Gracias. Lo hago con root y habia cambiado de router por lo que habilité una ip nueva para realizar el acceso remoto. Sigo sin poder realizar el update del   select. La instrucción que di creo que es erronea. Con la que trabajo ahora es: UPDATE consulta set consulta.estado=1 where (select * as consulta from articulos where articulos.estado<>1 limit 1,10)